# Can CSS3 `calc` variables be shared globally?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way in CSS3 to create a global variable and use it in various classes?

```
--divHeight: 100px;
.div1 {
    height: calc(var(--divHeight) + 10px);
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
    height: calc(var(--divHeight) - 10px);
    background-color: red;
}
```

I tried this and it won't work. Is there a way? The reason I need this is because I often have to design pages which have a header and a content section. The header has a fixed height and the content section should occupy the remaining height. For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       .header {
         height: 70px;
         background-color: red;
       }
       .content {
         height: calc(100vh - 70px);
         background-color: green;
       }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="header">
        Hello
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Hello
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So in the future, if the header's height has to be changed to `100px`, the height in the content section also has to be changed.

I know we can do this via JavaScript, but I would like to know if there is a pure CSS3 way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, just declare the variable on the root element. That has in fact been the only supported place for variables to occur for some time. You can read more about variables [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

```css
:root {
  --divHeight: 100px;
}

.div1 {
    height: calc(var(--divHeight) + 10px);
    width: calc(var(--divHeight) + 10px);
    background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
    height: calc(var(--divHeight) - 10px);
    width: calc(var(--divHeight) - 10px);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```